# What does paddr, baddr, laddr, haddr, and hvaddr refer to?

Tags: radare2

When I run `ie`, I get multiple addresses.

```
[0x41417641]> ie
[Entrypoints]
vaddr=0x080483d0 paddr=0x000003d0 baddr=0x08048000 laddr=0x00000000 haddr=0x00000018 hvaddr=0x08048018 type=program
```

What does baddr, laddr, haddr, and hvaddr refer to? When I run `ieq` for `[q]uite`, I get the `vaddr`. What's the difference between that and the other addresses listed under the entry point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time, you would not need any of these except the `vaddr` and the `paddr`. Since thoroughly explaining each of these names would take too much time, I'll share here the short meaning of each of these keywords. Most of them should be easy to understand.

- vaddr -  Virtual Address
- paddr -  Physical Address
- laddr -  Load Address
- baddr -  Base Address
- haddr -  e_entry\AddressOfEntryPoint in binary header
- hvaddr - Header Physical Address
- hpaddr - e_entry\AddressOfEntryPoint offset in binary header